# Making a Smooth Animation when Movement is from an array

Tags: java

I am in the final stages of making a Pacman game for Computer Science class. My game functions as it should except for one key thing. It's choppy. I know the reason why it's choppy but I do not know how to fix it. My problem is that I am multiplying by 21 from and array (below) for Pacman's and the Ghost's Coords. And I have a delay off 100ms meaning pacman is moving 21 pixels every 100ms which is not smooth.

Here is what the array looks like in case it matters:

```
public int board[][] =
  {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, //1
    {2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2}, //2
    {2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, //3
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //4
    {2,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}, //5
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //6
    {2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2}, //7
    {2,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2}, //8
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //9
    {5,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6}, //10
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, //11
    {2,2,2,2,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2}, //12
    {2,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2}, //13
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //14 - pacman on this row
    {2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2}, //15
    {2,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,2}, //16 
    {2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2}, //17
    {2,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,2}, //18
    {2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2}, //19
    {2,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,0,2}, //20
    {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2}}; //21
```

Basically each line is a row. The board is drawn from that. For the moving up for example it's just a matter of checking if the spot above the current location is clear and if it is add one to the array and multiply that by 21 for new position.

What I want to do is slow down Pacman's movement speed while at the same time making it smooth. If you require any other info I can provide some more snippets of code as well.

Edit: As requested here is the code. I know it's probably not all needed but I didn't know which parts would be needed to help to the fullest. And it's pretty much fully commented.

Here is a link to it since it's to long for the char limit here:
[Pastebin - Pacman](http://pastebin.com/SVEngXdP)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it would be a lot easier to just make a file containing the "rows" and then read from that. Also, post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is being drawn is probably more important than the abstract model. For instance BitSets as alternative will not say much.

How do you effect a repaint: `repaint(20L, x, y, width, height)` (restricted to changed area, being able to collect several changes over time)? How do you draw? Altering a `BufferedImage` would do. A BufferedImage can be written on (get a Graphics2D), so can draw sprites on it.

Choppy could also stem from a missing usage of `setDoubleBuffered(true)`. By the way 50 frames per second would be a repaint(20L).

You probably have a timer loop to animate the model, and view component(s) painted in the event thread - like one entire or 21x21 BufferedImages, and some semaphores for altering the view. Those semaphores might be a bottleneck, and 21x21 components might be more fine grained.

---

After receiving code:
*A redesign would be nicer, but probably not pragmatic.*

`Font`s and `Color`s should be created outside paintComponent, especially fonts are slow.
Style: `if (up == true)` should simply be `if (up)`; class names conventionally begin with a capital: `Draw`.

Both getResource and getResourceAsStream search on the class path and instead of the Windows backslash need a slash. (The class path can be inside a jar.) Fonts can be loaded likewise.

```
            sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream("Sounds/pac_chomp.wav")));
```

The sound management seems to be a bit simple, should probably be held globally, like the fonts, so the run-loop seems more "asynchrone", simply calling start, without loading.

Not so important, but:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
        System.arraycopy(newboard[r], 0, board[r], 0, board[r].length);
        // Replaces:
        //for (int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++) {
        //    board[r][c] = newboard[r][c];
        //}
    }
```

Still more clever would be to swap aliases:

```
int[][] physicalBoard0 = new int[21][21];
int[][] physicalBoard1 = new int[21][21];
boolean boardIs0 = true;
int[][] board = physicalBoard0;
int[][] newboard = physicalBoard1;

private void swapBoards() {
    boardIs0 = !boardIs0;
    if (boardIs0) {
        board = physicalBoard0;
        newBoard = physicalBoard1;
    } else {
        board = physicalBoard1;
        newBoard = physicalBoard0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not at all as advanced as your talking about. From a run method I'm calling other methods to check if the spot in front is clear. If it adds or subtracts depending on which way was pressed. Right now it's as simple as multiplying those array spots by 21. And at the end of the run method everything is repainted. Therefore about every 100ms it's being repainted again, and therefore pacman and the ghosts are then moved by 21 pixels in one of 4 directions.

Comment: Could you zip and email the images to me? joop_eggen at yahoo dot de.

Comment: I have sent you the email with everything included. I know the code is not efficient, and needs a redesign but, I am only in a Grade 11 Computer Science course and it's only my first semester in CS, therefore my skill level is still quite low.

Comment: I tried to send the email but apparently you don't have a yahoo.de account. I'm assuming you gave me the wrong email?

Comment: I do have such an account. Maybe you erred using a minus instead of an underscore? Maybe the file is too large (?)?

Comment: http://localhostr.com/files/4TjmlST/fail.png <<< Didn't work. Here is the download link: http://goo.gl/UoYpl

Comment: you left out the n in eggen; but thanks, the download link will do even better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6197/discussion-between-joop-eggen-and-fogest)

Comment: I'm in the chat right now! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6197/discussion-between-joop-eggen-and-fogest

Comment: From the chat: The problem is, is that it's not smooth. It's sometimes hard to get into paths. It's moving 21 pixels every 100s not including time it takes to run the code. So I need to lower those ms and descrease the amount of pixels moved. I also would like to slow pacman and the ghosts down and have them move based on a double's value. I don't know how to do this though

Comment: Can we take this to email, as chat during these days is a bit difficult for me? You have my email address. I will try to prepare a bit of code.

Comment: Okay I have sent you a email there. I might as well mark this as best answer then, since you can probably help me fine there.